# Characterization of bounded set in test function space?(Rudin)

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a subset of test function space $D(\Omega)$, then Rudin
(functional analysis) in Page 178 says that $E$ is bounded if and only if for any $f\in D'(\Omega)$ , the supremum sup$\{|f(\phi)|:\phi\in E\}$ is finite. How to prove that the latter implies the former?